# MongoDB: Collection don't show all inserted data

Tags: mongodb, collections, insert, records, displayobject

I've inserted couple of thousands records at once into MongoDB using JavaDriver and I try to display whole collection there wasn't even half of my project, but when I ask about quantity, it's show me correct value. What's a problem?

Comment: You need to include the code you used to write the data and the code you are using to display the collection

Answer (score 0):

By default the mongo command line client only displays the first 10 documents. You can alter the limit to say 123 via `db.my_collection.find().limit(123)`